# Closed form for $\int_0^\infty\arctan\Bigl(\frac{2\pi}{x-\ln\,x+\ln(\frac\pi2)}\Bigr)\frac{dx}{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form

I'm trying to find a closed form for this integral:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\arctan\left(\frac{2\pi}{x-\ln\,x+\ln\left(\frac\pi2\right)}\right)\frac{dx}{x+1}$$
Its approximate numeric value is
$$I\approx3.3805825284453469793953592216276992165696856825906055108192183...$$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like a rather unlikely candidate to have a closed form.  Why do you think it has one?  Does this expression arise somewhere in particular, or did you just make it up?

Comment: It arises in my computations, but they are too long to post them here.

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, because it lacks sufficient context, such as (1) where the integral comes from and (2) why the integral is of interest. Questions like this are likely to be put on hold.

Comment: @CarlMummert With all my respect, but I completely disagree. I do not care at all were this integral came from, or what purpose does it serve. Mathematics is not a purely utilitarian science, and many problems are interesting just on their own, because they are teasing our mind. It's always subjective of course, but a problem need not to be interesting to everybody to be on-topic here. I like almost all questions about definite integrals, especially ones like this, when we have a good candidate for a closed form, but it's not obvious at all how to get it.

Comment: Compare http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement

Comment: @CarlMummert: I think this question is of intrinsic interest. I would definitely like to see how one approaches this integral. In this, I agree with Vladimir. However, it would be nice to know where it comes from to have an idea that it does have a solution and what tools might be required. Cleo's answer shows that a solution is highly likely, and may urge others to look for that solution.

Comment: @CarlMummert If Ramanujan lived these days and used MSE, he would have probably told you that his integrals come from the Goddess of Namagiri (that is to answer (1)). It's hard to define what "of interest" is, but one reason for this interest is the art of mathematics that Ramanujan and Hardy at least would have never refused. "I could never resist an integral." - G. H. Hardy

Comment: @robjohn: if we went with "intrinsic interest", there would be no PSQ closing reason. Unfortunately, it is not possible to vote to close this question until the bounty expires - which was the main reason I left a comment. Cleo's answers are problematic for a different reason, which will eventually require moderator attention.

Comment: @Carl Mummert in my opinion your comments are problematic since you don't seem to understand how important is to know the closed form of such integrals, series. I'm here *only for these questions*. Let me tell you how I understand the question: well, the question is so difficult (in case you didn't realize) that it's even hard to find a starting point. So, I understand the OP. Besides that, the OP is known for posting questions that were proposed in some contest or from personal research. You should do some research and see the questions the OP posted so far.

Comment: @Chris'ssis: if the integral is of some paritcular importance, the OP could certainly explain that in the question. Just "being a hard integral" cannot be sufficient to make a question on-topic here. Otherwise someone could write a script to post hundreds of hard integals, at whatever limit the software allows them to be posted. The question in its current form does not *show* any research effort, or give any motivation for the integral. We can and should expect more than a PSQ from a user with 2,500 rep.

Comment: @CarlMummert I'm sure it's important to the OP at least, that's why he asked the question, but I don't think it *must* be of some particular importance to all of us. If "someone could write a script to post hundreds of hard integrals" that would be a totally different situation, the historical data of the present OP indicates that it's not the case here. The OP said "I'm trying to find a closed form for this integral", and one of the possible reasons we see no research effort is because the OP had nothing to show at that moment that is meaningful.

Comment: @Chris's sis: please see the link I posted above, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement . This conversation is probably already too long for the main site, and as I said above the main reason I left a comment in the first place is that it is impossible to vote to close until the bounty expires. These things have already been discussed at great length on the meta site.

Comment: @CarlMummert It depends on how you look at things. Here it's not much to show if referring to efforts shown. If you like, you may try to give an example of how the research efforts should look like to a question like this one. I mean not only simulated research efforts since if someone tells me that the integration by parts, or the change of variables don't work, say, it's of not help here, only a loss of time with the reading of an unmeanigful comment. Sometimes people simply don't see any way, so they have nothing to share.

Comment: @Chris'ssis you have to admit it would be convienent to know substitutions or series representations tried that way we don't repeat dead ends or even see a method we can work with better.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Computing a Related Contour Integral:**

Define
$$f(z)=\frac{i}{2}\frac{z-1}{1+az}\left(\frac{1}{z-\ln{z}+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{z-\ln{z}+2\pi i+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)$$
and let $\gamma$ denote a keyhole contour deformed around $[0,\infty]$. Restricting the argument between $0$ and $2\pi$, it is not hard to see that $f(z)$ has poles at $z=-\dfrac{1}{a}$, $z=-W_{-1}\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\pi i}{2}$, and $z=-W_0\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\dfrac{\pi i}{2}$. The residues at these poles are
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\frac{\pi i}{2}}f(z)
&=\frac{i}{2}\frac{\frac{\pi i}{2}-1}{\frac{\pi i}{2}a+1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{\pi i}}\\
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-\frac{\pi i}{2}}f(z)
&=\frac{i}{2}\frac{\frac{\pi i}{2}+1}{\frac{\pi i}{2}a-1}\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{\pi i}}\\
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-\frac{1}{a}}f(z)
&=-\frac{i}{2}u'(a)\left(\frac{1}{u(a)+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\pi i}+\frac{1}{u(a)+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\pi i}\right)\\
\end{align}
where $u(a)=\ln{a}-\dfrac{1}{a}$. By the residue theorem,
\begin{align}
\oint_{\gamma}f(z)\ dz
&=2\pi i\sum_{z_k\in\left\{-a^{-1}, \pm\pi i/2\right\}}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k}f(z)\\
&=\pi\left(\frac{2\left(u(a)+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{\left(u(a)+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2+\pi^2}u'(a)-\frac{2\pi^2a}{\pi^2a^2+4}\right)
\end{align}

---

**Parameterisation of the Contour Integral:**

We take the argument of $z$ to be $0$ above the branch cut, and $2\pi$ below the branch cut. Also, the contribution from the big arc is clearly $2\pi i\times\dfrac{i}{2}\times\dfrac{1}{a}\times (1+1)=-\dfrac{2\pi}{a}$. Taking all of these points into consideration, we eventually arrive at
\begin{align}
\oint_\gamma f(z)\ dz+\frac{2\pi}{a}
&=\small\frac{i}{2}\int^\infty_0\frac{x-1}{1+ax}\left(-\frac{1}{x-\ln|x|-2\pi i+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{x-\ln|x|+2\pi i+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\pi^2}\right)\ dx\\
&=2\pi\int^\infty_0\frac{x-1}{\left(x-\ln{x}+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}
{2}\right)\right)^2+4\pi^2}\frac{dx}{1+ax}\\
\end{align}

---

**Obtaining the Closed Form:**

Integrating with respect to $a$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\small\int^\infty_0\frac{2\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln(1+ax)}{\left(x-\ln{x}+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2+4\pi^2}\ dx
&\small=\ \pi\int\left(\frac{2\left(u(a)+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{\left(u(a)+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2+\pi^2}u'(a)-\frac{2\pi^2a}{\pi^2a^2+4}+\frac{2}{a}\right)\ da\\
&=\small\pi\left(\ln\left(\left(u(a)+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2+\pi^2\right)-\ln\left(\pi^2a^2+4\right)+\ln{a^2}\right)+\text{const.}\\
&=\small\pi\ln\left(\frac{\left(\ln{a}-\frac{1}{a}+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2+\pi^2}{\pi^2+\frac{4}{a^2}}\right)+\text{const.}
\end{align}
Letting $a\to 0$, [we find that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20%5Cpi%5Cln%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cln%7Ba%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%7D%2B%5Cln%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%5E2%2B%5Cpi%5E2%7D%7B%5Cpi%5E2%2B%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7Ba%5E2%7D%7D%5Cright%29%20as%20a%20to%200) the constant term is $\pi\ln{4}$. Plugging in $a=1$ and integrating by parts, we finally arrive at the closed form.
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{2\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln(1+x)}{\left(x-\ln{x}+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2+4\pi^2}\ dx
&=\int^\infty_0\arctan\left(\frac{2\pi}{x-\ln{x}+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)\frac{dx}{1+x}\\
&=\left.\pi\ln\left(\frac{\left(\ln{a}-\frac{1}{a}+\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2+\pi^2}{\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\frac{1}{a^2}}\right)\right|_{a=1}\\
&=\color{red}{\pi\ln\left(\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-2\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+1+\pi^2}{\frac{\pi^2}{4}+1}\right)}
\end{align}

Comment: Congrats!:-) Very instructive solution! +1

Comment: Nice! I assume $W$ is the [Lambert $W$-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), right?

Comment: @Vladimir Reshetnikov Yes, here $W$ refers to the Lambert W function.

Comment: How on earth do come up with the idea to choose $f(z)$ exactly like that??

Comment: Damn. 2 bounties!

Answer (score 39):

$$I=\pi\,\ln\left(\frac{1+\pi^2+\ln^2\left(\frac\pi2\right)-2\ln\left(\frac\pi2\right)}{1+\frac{\pi^2}4}\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

It is not very nice, but... integration by parts leads to:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\pi(x-1)\log(1+x)}{x^2+2x^2\log\frac{\pi}{2}+\left(4\pi^2+\log^2\frac{\pi}{2}\right)x-2x^2\log x+x\log x\log\frac{4\pi}{x^2}}\,dx$$
that, at least in principle, can be computed through the residue theorem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could shed light on how the poles of the integral are found.