# $W_{-1} (x)$ series expansion?

Tags: power-series, lambert-w

By the Lagrange Inversion Theorem, one can derive the series expansion for the principal branch of $W_0(x)$:
$$W_0(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-n)^{n-1}x^n}{n!}, \, |x| \leq \frac1e$$

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there also a series expansion for $W_{-1}(x)$? If so, how can it be derived?

Comment: [Here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/06/01/0004/) is a double series expansion for any branch of the W lambert function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lagrange reversion:**

$$\text W_{-1}(z)=\ln(z)-2i\pi-\ln(\ln(z)-2i\pi)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{S_n^{(m-n+1)}\ln^m(\ln(z)-2i\pi)}{(2\pi i-\ln(z))^nm!}\tag1$$

from [The Generalized Lambert function from Wolfram Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/06/01/0002/) and [the Stirling numbers of the first kind $S_n^{(m)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). If both sums go to $\infty$, then they are interchangeable. The derivation uses [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Lagrange%20reversion,of%20compositions%20with%20such%20functions.&text=Then%20for%20any%20function%20g%2C%20for%20small%20enough%20y%3A&text=In%20which%20case%20the%20equation%20can%20be%20derived%20using%20perturbation%20theory.):

$$We^W=z\implies W=\ln(z)-2\pi i -\ln(W)\implies W_{-1}(z)=\ln(z)-2\pi i+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}\ln^n(a)}{da^{n-1}}\right|_{a=\ln(z)-2\pi i}$$

Differentiating gives a [pattern](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Bln%28z%29%5En%2C%7Bz%2C10%7D%5D) with [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html):

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\ln^n(x)=x^{1-n}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}n^{(m)}S_{n-1}^{(m)}\ln^{n-m}(x)$$

The $n=1$ term does not fit this formula, so remove $\ln(\ln(z)-2\pi i)$ and simplify:

$$W_{-1}(z)=\ln(z)-2\pi i-\ln(\ln(z)-2\pi i)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{S_{n-1}^{(m)}(-1)^n\ln^{n-m}(\ln(z)-2\pi i)}{(\ln(z)-2\pi i)^{n-1}(n-m)!}$$

which [works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln%283.2%29-2+pi+i-ln%28ln%283.2%29-2+pi+i+%29%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2F%28n-m%29%21+%28ln%283.2%29-+2+pi+i%29%5E%281-n%29+stirlings1%28n-1%2Cm%29+ln%28ln%283.2%29-2+pi+i%29%5E%28n-m%29%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C10%7D%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C10%7D%5D). Then, some index shift gives $(1)$.

**Inverse gamma regularized:**

$$-Q^{-1}(2,-ez)-1\mathop=^{-\frac1e\le z<0}\text W_{-1}(z)=…-\frac{43}{135}(ex+1)^2-\frac{11}{72}(2ex+2)^\frac32-\frac23(ex+1)-\sqrt{2ex+2}-1 $$

[image]

From the [series expansion of Inverse Gamma Regularized](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized/06/01/03/0002/). Please correct me and give me feedback.

The series coefficients have a recurrence relation mentioned in [quantile mechanics](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahwts/lgsnotes/EJAM_Quantiles.pdf)

Comment: Using [this integral](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/07/01/0001/), we can get an integral representation for lambert w, numerically checked. Generalizing, it would work for any branch and give another one other than [this known one](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/07/01/01/)

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=xe^x$; so $x=W_{-1}(y)$, where $y\to 0^-$ as $x\to-\infty$.  Note
that $y=0$ is a logarithmic branch point for $W_{-1}(y)$.  The series for $x$ in terms of $y$ presumably begins like this:
$$
x = \log(-y) - \log(-\log(-y)) + \dots\qquad\text{as } y \to -\infty
$$

---

**Derivation** ... I prefer asymptotics for $X \to +\infty$, so write
$X=-x$ and $Y = -1/y$.  So $X \to +\infty$ and $Y\to + \infty$, with
$$
e^X = XY,
$$
$$
X = \log X + \log Y
\tag0$$
Now $\log X= o(X)$ so from $(0)$ we get
$$
X = \log Y + o(\log Y)
\tag1$$
That is the first approximation.
Next, compute
$$
\log X = \log(\log Y + \log X)
= \log\left((\log Y)\left(1+\frac{\log X}{\log Y}\right)\right)
= \log\log Y + \log\left(1+\frac{\log X}{\log Y}\right)
$$
Thus
$$
X = \log Y + \log\log Y + \log\left(1+\frac{\log X}{\log Y}\right)
$$
Here, $\log\log Y \to +\infty$, but $\log X/\log Y \to 0$ so
$\log\left(1+\frac{\log X}{\log Y}\right) \to 0$, so
$$
X = \log Y + \log\log Y + o(1)
\tag2$$
That is the second approximation.
We could continue this to get as many terms as we want.
The next term is not $\log\log\log Y$.  I think the next one is
$$
X = \log Y + \log\log Y + \frac{\log\log Y}{\log Y} + \dots
\tag3$$

Substitute in $(2)$ for $x, y$ to get
$$
W_{-1}(y) = x = \log(-y) - \log(-\log(-y)) + o(1)  \qquad\text{as } y \to -\infty
$$

Comment: Presumably? I don't see the derivation